# Factorials-sum and remainder

Tags: number-theory

What is the remainder when $1!+2!+3!....+100!$ is divided by $3$ and please can you explain the formula for finding sum of factorials?

Also is there a sequence for last digits when a factorial sum is divided by a prime number?

Comment: $1!+2!$ is divisible by $3,$ and so is $n!$ for $n\ge3$

Comment: Thanks for the help.